# Jedis connection with proxy

Tags: java, proxy, redis, nosql, jedis

I'm using Jedis, I cannot connect directly to Redis, I have to use a proxy.
Can I connect to `Redis` with `Jedis` using a socks proxy?

Can you help me, please.

Regards.

Comment: You can refer the link https://serverfault.com/questions/445169/how-do-i-configure-redis-to-allow-me-to-connect-through-a-socks-proxy

Comment: Can I do it with Jedis?

Comment: No, it does not work: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/pull/1707

Comment: @mp911de your example does not work? Any solution?

Comment: @MichelFoucault, do you have an answer on how to do this?

Comment: @RenanGeraldo I resolved it with an internal HAproxy

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution but could n't find any. So I have done the following changes to fix this issue:

```
 @NotNull
    private ProxySelector proxySelector() {
        return new ProxySelector() {
            @Override
            public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
                List<Proxy> proxies = new LinkedList<>();
                InetSocketAddress socketAddress =
                    new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
                proxies.add(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, socketAddress));
                return proxies;
            }

            @Override
            public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException e) {
                log.error(String.format(
                    "Connection to proxy server %s with socket address %s failed with error. %s",
                    uri, sa, e));
            }
        };
    }
```

and  then set the default proxy selector:
`ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector());`